# Border Cornered with blank space on top

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar (menu), and I need to add a cornered border, whenever the user hovers over it.

```
<nav>
<a href="#home">Home</a> |
<a href="#about">About</a> |
<a href="#blog">Blog</a> |
<a href="#others">My Others Services</a>
</nav>
```

The border I need to build is this:

[image]

Is this possible to do with CSS?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Most certainly.

One way to do this is by leveraging the css pseudo-elements.

When the user hovers over the anchor tag, that tag will now have a before and after pseudo-elements of your desired padding+color. They will also have a border on the top and the bottom edge. Additionally, the before pseudo-element will include a border to its left side and the after pseudo-element on its right side.

This results in giving the links that "cornered border" look as only the pseudo-elements are bordered (from the sides) leaving the inside space empty for text.

P.S. I am using the css variable to store the border color.

```css
body {
  --nav-hover: gold;
}

a:hover {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--nav-hover);
}

a:hover::before,
a:hover::after {
  content: '';
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--nav-hover);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--nav-hover);
}

a:hover::before {
  border-left: 1px solid var(--nav-hover);
}

a:hover::after {
  border-right: 1px solid var(--nav-hover);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#home">Home</a> |
  <a href="#about">About</a> |
  <a href="#blog">Blog</a> |
  <a href="#others">My Others Services</a>
</nav>
```